# Are local IP addresses on home routers always IPv4?

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, ipv4

What the title says.

I want to know whether I can assume all internal IP addresses supplied by a regular home router will be IPv4 or might they be IPv6 as well?

Comment: There are many different models of home routers. Some do support dual stack IPv4 and IPv6 including (but probably not limited to) any home router running openwrt or ddwrt.

Comment: @Mark Just to verify - you mean _internal_ IPv6 addresses?

Comment: This is very broad--there are so many different models of routers out there. "regular home router" is not specific, could be anything from the free box your ISP gives you to a Turris Omnia or some of the Unifi prosumer home router kit (both of which support ipv6 out of the box and can provide ipv6 addresses to clients).

Comment: yes, my clients on my network get an IPv6 from the router if they ask for one (running openwrt on a "home router") https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/ipv6/start

Comment: @Mark I wasn't really asking about prosumer, more about the basic types non-techies would have in their homes, however, from the tone of your comments I see that I shouldn't assume it'll always be IPv4, just like the answer below. Thanks.

Comment: There are so many different models out there. Some do, many don't. You can put better firmware on many ISP provided routers that will provide this functionality, if it's not available by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may depend upon the router, but a number of routers I have had allow a choice of IPv4 or IPv6 internally and externally.

I suggest you access the GUI setup of your router and check the WAN and LAN detail settings.

You cannot make an assumption - you must check your own situation.

Comment: Thanks. (+1) Can't accept yet (SuperUser system, not me).

Comment: You should be able to accept. I am not entirely certain but I think you can.

Comment: There's a minimum waiting time to accept. When I wrote the comment above I tried accepting and was notified I have to wait another 4 minutes. Anyway, now I can, and have. Thanks again.